# Rmarkdown knitr problem with £ pound sterling symbol not displaying correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

When I include the £ sterling symbol in text when using knitr and kableExtra this displays as <U+00A3> in the output.

Is there any way I can get £ symbol to display with kableExtra and knitr?

I am using R 3.6.0 and package versions knitr_1.29 and kableExtra_1.1.0.

Example code below:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)

library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(xtable)
````

````
```{r make a table, results='asis'}

# input metric
MI_input1 <- data.frame(cbind(c("£15.5m",""),c("£32.3m","157%"),c("","")))


# create MI table
MI_table1 <- kableExtra::kable(MI_input1, col.names = NULL, align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling("bordered", full_width = F) %>%
  pack_rows("Value in £", 1, 2, label_row_css = "text-align: center") %>% 
  column_spec(1:3, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
  row_spec(1:2, align = "c")

MI_table1
````

Comment: You may use backslash as the escape character in R strings: `"Value in \u00A3"` or try to set the correct encoding (File > Save with Encoding... > UTF-8).

Comment: "... R allows typing Unicode characters by entering `\u...` or `\U...` — with `...` standing for a 4-digit hexadecimal code) or `\U...` (with `...` standing for a longer hexadecimal code — inside a character string and replacing the `...` with the appropriate code of the desired symbol" - [9.2 Essentials of text data](https://bookdown.org/hneth/ds4psy/9-2-text-essentials.html).

Comment: @RadovanMiletić replacing £ with \u00A3 worked and it now displays correctly after being knitted. Thank you!